# VSCode include errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I got a cpp project in VS Code but I get an error in the editor

[image: error in editor]

I have this in my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and I can build/run/debug by pressing the buttons in the bottom of the editor window.

[image: bottom build buttons]

I can build/run using cmake

```
cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
cmake --build build
```

[image]

But I cant use the run/debug button in the top right corner. Then I get an error complaining  "'iostream' file not found". How do I solve this problem? I dont want to see include error messages and be able to use the build/run buttons

Comment: just use cmake? I'm guessing that button is from code runner or similar plugins? They really don't work for anything other than basic c++ programs, you'll need to study the documentation for the plugin for how to configure it

Comment: The buttons is not a big deal, I can live with that :) The annoying problem is the warnings in the editor

Comment: You should delete the `c_cpp_properties.json` and let the cmake plugin configure it automatically (or just use visual studio which is so much easier to use than vscode)

Comment: I suggest you take a look through [the existing Q&A](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22visual-studio-code%22+iostream+not+found+site%3Astackoverflow.com)